# TypeError: name must be a byte string

Tags: python, terminal, tensorflow, anaconda

I am attempting to upgrade my tensorflow via conda but am having some issues. I am following the Anaconda installation procedure [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#installing_with_anaconda).

I am getting an error when I execute the `conda create -n tensorflow` command.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 479, in conda_exception_handler
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 145, in _main
        exit_code = args.func(args, p)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 68, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'create')
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 238, in install
        prefix=prefix)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/api.py", line 24, in get_index
        index = fetch_index(channel_urls, use_cache=use_cache, unknown=unknown)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 300, in fetch_index
        repodatas = [(u, f.result()) for u, f in zip(urls, futures)]
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 75, in func
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 117, in fetch_repodata
        timeout=(6.1, 60))
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
        body=body, headers=headers)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 784, in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 252, in connect
        ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 296, in ssl_wrap_socket
        cnx.set_tlsext_host_name(server_hostname)
      File "/Users/madhavthaker/Downloads/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1232, in set_tlsext_host_name
        raise TypeError("name must be a byte string")
    TypeError: name must be a byte string
```

I'm done some googling and haven't been able to find a useful response. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your conda is using python 2.7, you may have to upgrade it to python 3.x

I say this because in the anaconda installation guide you linked, it shows a call to print with parentheses, which is python 3 syntax

Comment: Something seems off. Even when I try to install a python 3.5 environment on anacanda using `conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda`, I get the same error

Comment: Make sure your new error messages have python3.5 in their path. Otherwise  it seems to be a problem with SSL.py , here's an issue related to it: https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/issues/161

Comment: Same issue here: https://github.com/beetbox/beets/issues/2098 , he seemed to fix it by upgrading pip and cryptography using easy_install, so maybe if you can upgrade those packages on your conda's python then try again